# Why am I getting a repeated modifier error when compiling?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public final class FileListing2 
{
    public static void main(String... aArgs) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
         File startingDirectory= new File(aArgs[0]);
         List<File> files = FileListing.getFileListing(startingDirectory);
         //print out all file names, in the the order of File.compareTo()
         for(File file : files )
         {
              System.out.println(file);
         }
    }
    static public List<File> getFileListing(File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        validateDirectory(aStartingDir);
        List<File> result = getFileListingNoSort(aStartingDir);
        Collections.sort(result);
        return result;
    }
    static private List<File> getFileListingNoSort(File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
          List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
          File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles();
          List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
          for(File file : filesDirs) 
          {
            result.add(file); //always add, even if directory
            if ( ! file.isFile() ) 
            {
                   //must be a directory
                   //recursive call!
                   List<File> deeperList = getFileListingNoSort(file);
                   result.addAll(deeperList);
            }
            return result;
          }

       }
       static private void validateDirectory (File aDirectory) throws FileNotFoundException 
       {
          if (aDirectory == null) 
          {
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory should not be null.");
          }
          if (!aDirectory.exists()) 
          {
                 throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory does not exist: " + aDirectory);
          }
          if (!aDirectory.isDirectory()) 
          {
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Is not a directory: " + aDirectory);
          }
          if (!aDirectory.canRead()) 
          {
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory cannot be read: " + aDirectory);
           }
        }
      }
```

I copied this code from [this site](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68) and am trying to adapt it for our environment. Unfortunately, I can't get the $%!@#*($ thing to compile. I keep getting an error at the main method: error: repeated modifier.

`public static void main(String... aArgs) throws FileNotFoundException` is the line flagged for the error.

I don't see any duplicate modifiers in here,  All my curly braces and parens appear to be in the right places, and I am completely stumped.

This is my first time working with varargs...I'm not sure if ~that's~ giving me an issue? I scanned Java Documentation, but didn't spot any red flags. Besides, it compiles just fine when I change `String...` to `String[]`. I feel I may get some null values, so I'd prefer to leave `String...` in the method.

Anyone see anything that I'm missing? I feel like I'm looking at that Paris in the
the spring brainteaser....

Comment: Can you point out which line is giving you the compile issue?

Comment: `main(String... aArgs` does java support elipse?

Comment: The way your code is formatted is neither common nor does it make errors easy to see. Please consider using a common code formatter (most IDEs have one integrated).

Comment: Line 8 needs to be changed to FileListing2.getFileListing(startingDirectory) Then you need to add/fix a return to getFileListingNoSort. Then it should compile.  Edit: Repeated what Oscar said below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the method `getFileListingNoSort()` the line `return result;` is outside of the method, move it one line up to put it inside, where it belongs.

Comment: @dwwilson66 Same error: `return result;` is misplaced in the updated code; it should be in the last line in the method, _just before_ the closing `}`. Also, in the second line of the `main()` method use `FileListing2` instead of `FileListing`

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce your repeated modifier error (using JDK 1.7.0), but the return statement of the method `getFileListingNoSort` is not in the method body.

Please format your code so that it makes sense and you will see such issues. The following compiles fine:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public final class FileListing2 {
    public static void main( String... aArgs ) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File startingDirectory = new File( aArgs[0] );
        List<File> files = FileListing2.getFileListing( startingDirectory );
        for(File file : files) {
            System.out.println( file );
        }
    }


    static public List<File> getFileListing( File aStartingDir ) throws FileNotFoundException {
        validateDirectory( aStartingDir );
        List<File> result = getFileListingNoSort( aStartingDir );
        Collections.sort( result );
        return result;
    }


    static private List<File> getFileListingNoSort( File aStartingDir ) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles();
        List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList( filesAndDirs );
        for(File file : filesDirs) {
            result.add( file ); // always add, even if
                                        // directory
            if(!file.isFile()) {
                List<File> deeperList = getFileListingNoSort( file );
                result.addAll( deeperList );
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    static private void validateDirectory( File aDirectory ) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if(aDirectory == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Directory should not be null." );
        }
        if(!aDirectory.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException( "Directory does not exist: " + aDirectory );
        }
        if(!aDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Is not a directory: " + aDirectory );
        }
        if(!aDirectory.canRead()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Directory cannot be read: " + aDirectory );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cut/pasted your code, adjsuted the filename to FileListing3 so as not to overwrite the old version. Same error: `C:\Users\x46332\Desktop\dev\java\bin>javac FileListing3.java` `.\FileListing.java:22: error: repeated modifier` `public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException` ` ^ ` I'm running java version "1.7.0_02"